# OpenAM : How to direct a user to own portal log-in page instead of openAm log-in page

Tags: openam

Can someone please help me in finding the solution for below question? I have been struggling for last 2 days and am not able to reach conclusive decision. [Disclaimer: I am still in nascent phase ..:(]

Whether it is possible to launch our own web application(portal) log-in page instead of openAm log-in page. Right now I are able to access protected page after successful authentication on openAm log-in page.
    I was able to customize the openAm pages (according to our look and feel) in openAM portal ,but this added dependency on openAM version. I will again have to redo/copy paste the changes in new openam version.

Any lead/pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to rely on OpenAM you have to create an auth-wrapper/interface used by your portal. The implementation can use either OpenAM's REST API or SDK to perform authentication. If you want to do SSO as well be sure to send OpenAM's SSO tracking cookie back to the client.

But if OpenAM's API changes for some reason you have to adopt the implementaion as well ... so you still have some OpenAM dependency there.

If you do not want to customize OpenAM directly you could deploy OpenAM DistAuth along with your portal app ... and customize this. This allows you to customize Login pages independent from OpenAM.

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard for your reply!!!:). How frequent OpenAM's API changes? I hope its not that frequent? Also with REST API approach , do we still need to use agent(I am using J2EE)? Going further I have 3 approaches to integrate with openAM 1. Modify OpenAm pages directly and use it with my portal 2. Use REST API 3. Use DistAuth. Out these,which is the cleanest/industry standard approach? I know the decision will depend on lot of requirements,but still I wanted to know which approach is cleanest and covers majority of use cases. Thanks in advance ..:)

Comment: OpenAM has not changed much in the past , but there will be a new 'backbone.js' base Login framework called XUI as the one used has it's root at Sun Microsystems and used the Java System Application Framework which is closed source and not maintained anymore so it has to be replaced sooner or later.

You can build your own login pages based on OpenAM REST or Java API, REST API is currently enhancing; Java API has been stable for a very long time.

If you build your own login stuff, you have to understand how OpenAM proprietary SSO works.
Agents are a different story, you may read tech overview